# How to use backreferences in PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace, backreference

I want to add a character to the end of each file extension found in a body of text using preg_replace().

Here is some sample text:

```
$string='http://www.mysite.com/expert/images/imageone.jpghttp://www.mysite.com/expert/images/imagetwo.jpg';
```

This search & replace works fine in TextWrangler, appending a semi colon to file extensions:

```
(\.(jpg|gif|html?|php|tiff?|pdf|png))


\1;
```

Translated to PHP, however does not work, having no effect; no errors.

```
preg_replace("/(\.(jpg|gif|html|php|tif|tiff|pdf|htm|png))/","\\1;",$string);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works perfectly for me, but you should try using `$1`:

```
$string = preg_replace("/.../","$1;",$string);
```

or put the replacement in single quotes:

```
$string = preg_replace("/.../",'\\1;',$string);
```

Comment: @Slinky: Then the error must be somewhere else. Make sure you have `error_reporting(E_ALL)`. You must also assign the value back to `$string` in case you are not doing this.

Comment: Yes, I was not assigning the result back to a variable. Thanks